# Save and Restor tensorflow model with numpy weights

Tags: numpy, math, tensorflow

Please help me to restore simple tensorflow model by numpy way, here is:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,196])

# 19 because 0-18 possible numbers
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([196,19]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([19]))

# Create the Graph
y = tf.matmul(x,W) + b 

# Loss and Optimizer
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,19])

# Cross Entropy
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=2.5)

train = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)

### Create Session
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Train the model for 1000 steps on the training set
    # Using built in batch feeder
    def batch(array:"[[]]"=[], step:"int"= 2):
        for i in range(0,len(array),step):
            yield  array[i:i+step]

    batch_generator_x = batch(x_train, step = 100)
    batch_generator_y = batch(y_train, step = 100)

    while True:     
        try:
            batch_x = batch_generator_x.__next__()
            batch_y = batch_generator_y.__next__()
            sess.run(train,feed_dict={x:batch_x,y_true:batch_y})
        except StopIteration:
            break

    # Test the Train Model
    matches = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1),tf.argmax(y_true,1))
    acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(matches,tf.float32))

    print(sess.run(acc,feed_dict={x:x_eval,y_true:y_eval}))
```

here, I am saved my model matrix weights and bias:

```
    W_val, b_val = sess.run([W, b])

    np.savetxt("W.csv", W_val, delimiter=",")
    np.savetxt("b.csv", b_val, delimiter=",")
```

then I am thinking that I should do this for restoring:

```
W = np.loadtxt("W.csv",delimiter=",").astype(np.float32)
b = np.loadtxt("b.csv",delimiter=",").astype(np.float32)

x = x_eval[0] # "image" example

y = x*W + b #prediction
```

but how to predict if W.shape - (196, 19) and x.shape - (196,)

I am understand why this `#ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (196,) (196,19)` but how this operation tensorflow is doing ?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I highly recommend you save and restore the model using tensorflow's checkpoints, it's so so much easier than what you're attempting:

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model

But if you really really want to export and import the weights manually (which you absolutely can do), you need to understand tensorflow's declarative programming methodology. All tensorflow operations and tensors (variables) are symbolic and exist in a container called a computation graph. You can't set `W = np.loadtxt(...)` because you're trying to set W to a numeric value, but W is a symbol, it's literally a python Object that only represents some data that may or may not exist in memory. It is **NOT** data.

Now, to do it the way you described you are going to need to define a placeholder to hold those weights you're passing in, then define an assign operation, and then interact with the whole thing through sess.run. Here's a little psuedo-code which I haven't tested to illustrate:

```
weights_placeholder = tf.placeholder(some_appropriate_shape)
assign_op = tf.assign(W, weights_placeholder)

sess.run(assign_op, feed_dict={weights_placeholder: np.loadtxt(...)})
```

Comment: Thank you for attention, I know the standard ways to save and restore model, but problem is because I would like to test final weights without tensorflow.     If I am do network by myself , like always, the count of columns in the first matrix(input) will be is equal to the rows count in the second, but what is with tensorflow ?  Becuse W.shape - (196, 19)  - it is look like 196 matrix of 19 fiches, but I need (196,) weights

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, why would your weight vector be 196? And what is a fiche? Do you mean there are 19 classes? Are you perhaps referring to the expected output shape? The weight matzx transforms one layer size to another. Your prediction is y, which will be 19. What did you mean about predicting W.shape?

Comment: yes, classes, in simple I cant do this y = x*W + b, becuase W.shape - (196, 19) and x.shape - (196,)